# Reproduce CSS property in StackPanels : Space Between

Tags: wpf, xaml, stackpanel

Is it possible in XAML to automatically separate elements in a `StackPanel` no matter what the size of the window is?

In CSS with the property : space between you can send elements to both sides of the parent. This is what I want to reproduce. Is it possible ?

[image: Two black squares on a grey background alinged left and right with a space in between.]

Comment: if it's always two elements, then use [Grid](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/grid-rows-and-columns/) with 3 Columns, put item1 column=0, item2 column=2, Stackpanel can't span the way, you describe

Comment: I didn't think of it but could maybe work. How would you do if i was a wrap panel filled with a list ?

Comment: Maybe you describe your intention, before starting guessing on several Control types :) Wrappanel, is basically a stackpanel which overflows in a new row,when the  available width is exceeded..

Answer (score 0):

A [`StackPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.stackpanel?view=net-5.0) does not work this way , see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.stackpanel?view=net-5.0). It does not have a notion of the available space or remaining space to divide, it just *stacks* elements in one direction.

> Arranges child elements into a single line that can be oriented horizontally or vertically.

What you can do instead is use a `DockPanel`. It allows stacking controls to either side of the panel and by default the last element added to it fills the remaining space. The `Border` here serves as a dummy element to take the remaining space. Usually, you would put a control there that is actually used. Please be aware that this example only reproduces what you explicitly asked for, the panel allows for much more complex layouts. See [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.dockpanel?view=net-5.0#remarks) from the documentation.

```
<DockPanel>
   <Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="Left" Fill="Black" Width="100" Height="100"/>
   <Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="Right" Fill="Black" Width="100" Height="100"/>
   <Border/>
</DockPanel>
```

An alternative is to use a `Grid` with three columns, where the left and right columns use `Auto` as `Width` so the contained controls only take up as much space as they need, while the center column has its `Width` set to `*`, which will make it fit the remaining space.

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="Black" Width="100" Height="100"/>
   <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Fill="Black" Width="100" Height="100"/>
</Grid>
```

The relevant portion on [size attributes for `Grid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid?view=net-5.0#remarks):

> Columns and rows that are defined within a `Grid` can take advantage of Star sizing to distribute remaining space proportionally. When Star is selected as the height or width of a row or column, that column or row receives a **weighted proportion of the remaining available space**. This is in contrast to `Auto`, which distributes space evenly **based on the size of the content** that is within a column or row.

---

Update for your list example. You can define a data template for the items.

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="25,60,25,25" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Border Padding="0,25" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" BorderBrush="#3D3C44">
            <Grid Width="378" Background="black">
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="hello" Foreground="white"/>
               <Border Grid.Column="1" x:Name="PlaceholderForYourContentAndBindings" Background="Red"/>
              <theme:OnOff Grid.Column="2" Height="21" Width="38" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" Toggle="{Binding status , Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MouseLeftButtonDown="OnOff_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
            </Grid>
         </Border>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>   
</ListView>
```

[image: ListView with a WrapPanel.]

If you want two fixed columns in the `ListView`, use a `UniformGrid` instead of a `WrapPanel` and remove the fixed sizes. With an `ItemContainerStyle` the items will then scale with the window.

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ItemsSource="{Binding StringItems}">
   <ListView.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <UniformGrid Columns="2" Margin="25,60,25,25" />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemsPanel>
   <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
      </Style>
   </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Border Padding="0,25" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" BorderBrush="#3D3C44">
            <Grid  Background="black">
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="hello" Foreground="white"/>
               <Border Grid.Column="1" x:Name="PlaceholderForYourContentAndBindings" Background="Red"/>
               <theme:OnOff Grid.Column="2" Height="21" Width="38" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" Toggle="{Binding status , Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MouseLeftButtonDown="OnOff_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
            </Grid>
         </Border>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

[image: ListView with UniformGrid.]